# How to show Page Level Error and Inline Level Error using react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How to show Page Level Error and Inline Level Error using react hook form such that  inline error msg  will display on onBlur and Page level error msg should display on onSubmit.

I want to show pageLevel Error only when i click next button of the form . And Inline level error on onBlur

Answer (score 0):

To show page-level and inline-level errors using React Hook Form, you can follow the steps below:

Install React Hook Form: Make sure you have React Hook Form installed in your project. You can install it using npm or yarn:

npm install react-hook-form

Set up a form: Create a form component and import the necessary functions and components from React Hook Form.

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function MyForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {/* Form fields go here */}
      <input type="text" name="username" ref={register({ required: true })} />
      {/* Error message for inline-level validation */}
      {errors.username && <p>This field is required.</p>}

      {/* Other form fields */}
      {/* ... */}

      {/* Page-level error message */}
      {Object.keys(errors).length > 0 && (
        <p>There are errors in the form. Please fix them.</p>
      )}

      {/* Submit button */}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default MyForm;
```

Register form fields: Use the register function from React Hook Form to register your form fields and specify the validation rules. In the example above, the "username" field is registered with the required rule.

Show inline-level error: To show an error message for a specific field, you can check the errors object for that field and display the error message conditionally. In the example above, the error message for the "username" field is displayed if the errors.username property exists.

Show page-level error: You can check if the errors object has any properties to determine if there are any validation errors in the form. If there are errors, you can display a page-level error message. In the example above, the page-level error message is displayed if Object.keys(errors).length > 0.

Handle form submission: In the onSubmit function, you can handle the form submission logic. In the example above, the form data is logged to the console.

By following these steps, you can show page-level and inline-level errors using React Hook Form. Customize the error messages and validation rules according to your specific requirements.

Comment: This looks a lot like a ChatGPT answer.